# Android Tab Layout how to start from the second tab

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, tabs

Hi I am following this tut
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

and I want the App to start with "Games" Tab not the "Top Rated" !,  can u plz help me in this :)

here is my code

```
package com.scorebeyond.android.tabswithswipeexample;

import com.scorebeyond.android.tabswithswipeexample.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    // Tab Titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(-1);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {

            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));

        }

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected

                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        // On tab selected
        // show respected fragment view

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

thx alot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use (at the end of your onCreate method):

[action bar selectTab method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#selectTab%28android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab%29) using the tab you previously added as parameter

or

select the tab item by position using [Action Bar setSelectedNavigationItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setSelectedNavigationItem%28int%29)

> actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(1);

Answer (score 1):

Use Android [TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) and its method [setCurrentTab()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setCurrentTab%28int%29) in your onCreate()-method.